# Why this Javascript code is behaving asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a html-file, looks like:

```
...
<div class="colorbox" data-product="oldUpload" data-color="brown" style="background-color: #31261d" title="Brown"></div>
<div class="colorbox" data-product="oldUpload" data-color="cranberry" style="background-color: #6e0a25" title="Cranberry"></div>
...
<div class="colorbox" data-product="TSHIRT" data-color="brown" style="background-color: #31261d" title="Brown"></div>
<div class="colorbox" data-product="TSHIRT" data-color="cranberry" style="background-color: #6e0a25" title="Cranberry"></div>
...
<script src="profiles.js"></script>
```

And following JavaScript file:

```
function getSelectedColors() {
  let colorboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('colorbox');
  let selectedColors = [];
  for (let colorbox of colorboxes) {
    if (colorbox.classList.contains('checked')) {
        selectedColors[colorbox.dataset.product] = (selectedColors[colorbox.dataset.product] || '') + colorbox.dataset.color + ',';
    }
  }
  console.log('Colors:' + selectedColors);
  console.log(selectedColors);
  return selectedColors;
}
```

If I run the function getSelectedColors() the output in console is:

> Line 1: "Colors: "
>
> Line 2: "[oldUpload: "brown,cranberry,pink,purple,", TSHIRT: "cranberry,...]"

So it seems, the code in function is asynchronous, because "selectedColors" is an empty array directly after for-loop and the function also returns an empty array. But at the moment, I don't understand why, because I think, there's nothing asynchronous in my code.

So why this JS code is behaving asynchronous?

Thanks,
Klaus

Comment: Are you running this in Chrome? The Chrome console is fairly notorious for doing weird things like this.

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, that was just an error in writing my question. I just fixed it.

Comment: @MaheerAli: The script tag is already at the end. I will edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: No, your code is not asynchronous. "*"selectedColors" is an empty array directly after for-loop*" - what makes you think that? Though yes, of course, the array will still have a `.length` of `0`. What the console shows you are non-index properties of the array object. [Don't abuse arrays like that!](https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)

Comment: @Eric yes, th doc should be definitly ready, beause the javascript file is included at the end

Comment: Unless `colorbox.dataset.product` is an integer index, this looks like an improper usage of arrays, should be an object instead.

Comment: @Bergi I don't check the length of the array. I only check the result, like you see on the console.log statements. I also checked the return value.

Comment: @KlausSchreiber Uh, but the "*`[oldUpload: "brown,cranberry,pink,purple,", TSHIRT: "cranberry,...]`*" that you see in the console doesn't look empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change
`let selectedColors = [];` to `let selectedColors = {};`

In JS spec arrays only have a numeric index. Other indices are not enumerated and so "invisible" in your console.

Answer (score 0):

```
  'Colors:' + selectedColors
```

Through concatenating the array with a string, the array gets implicitly converted to a string. That will join all the values of the array:

```
 "" + [1, 2, 3] // "1,2,3"
```

In your case the array is actually empty, it contains no numerical keys.